# Android SQLite crash in emulator but not phone?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sqlite

I'm having an interesting issue where my code runs fine on my phone, but when running on the emulator i get a crash as soon as the app tries to get a value from the database.

Here is the DB Helper function which is crashing it

```
/** Used to retrieve our lowest stored val */
public int GetLowestVal(){

    // Get our databases results
    Cursor result = null;
    try { 
        // Get our databases results
        result = super.getAll();

    } catch( SQLException anyDbError ) { 
        // Errors? TODO
    } finally { 
        // Finally TODO
    }


    // Setup initial lowest val
    int lowestVal = 0;

    // Move through results and compare them
    while( result.moveToNext() ){
        // Get our place from the DB
        int index = Integer.parseInt(result.getString(1).trim());

        // Last index should be lowest
        if ( index == 10){
            lowestVal = Integer.parseInt(result.getString(3).trim());
        }   
    }

    // Return our value
    return lowestVal;

}
```

And the error it throws is:

> getWriteableDatabase() was called recursively.

Comment: Show us a full stack trace please.

Comment: Sorry do you mean the logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, the problem was that i was trying to edit the table still in the `onCreate()` method which causes `getWrteableDatabase()` to be called recursively.

The reason it wasn't working on the emulator but worked on the phone was because the database had been created on the phone before anything was added to `onCreate`, but deploying it on other devices caused the crash.